# Error: In stack of struct in go-lang get overwrite? How can we do deep-copy of struct in golang?

Tags: go, struct, hashmap, deep-copy

I have created a stack of struct in Go.

```golang
type Stack struct {
    stack []Vehicle
}
```

I have this struct and method to create a new struct instance:-

```golang
type Vehicle struct {
Name string
Quantity map[string]interface{}
}

function NewVehicle(name string) *Vehicle {
v := &Vehicle{Name:name}
v.Quantity = make(map[string]interface{})
return v
}
```

What I am doing for example:-

```golang
m := NewVehicle("Two Wheeler")
m.Quantity['a'] = 10

// pushing stack 
Stack.push(clone(m))

m.Quantity['a'] = 20

Stack.pop(m)
```

Expected:-

As I pushed instance with `Quantity['a'] = 10` when I pop
the stack then it should give me value `10 of Quantity['a']`

Actual:-

I am getting the value `20 of Quantity['a']`

```golang
function clone(vehicle Vehicle*){}
```

Can anybody help in this, how deep copy of the struct before pushing in the stack? or what will be in the clone method to deep copy the struct?

Answer (score 1):

Map is a pointer to the actual map object, so if you need to deep-copy it, you have to do it manually:

```
func (v Vehicle) Copy() *Vehicle {
   ret:=NewVehicle(v.Name)
   for k,v:=range v.Quantity {
       ret[k]=v
   }
   return ret
}
...

stack.push(m.Copy())
```

Comment: NewVehicle is return a pointer of struct then how will this work with that?

Comment: NewVehicle is return pointer